# Filter across pages in Google datastudio

Tags: filter, looker-studio

I have a multi page report with Page 1 having a Table chart with filter interactions ON. When I click on a row in this Table chart, I need my other pages also to get filtered based on this row selection.

If I make this table chart report-level, then this table chart will be visible in other pages which I do not want. What is the best possible way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use a [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) (set to [Report-level](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9188171)) instead of a [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044); additionally, a default selection could be set.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3245f52e-485f-43b6-9aa4-f9250e7a1702) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but how i solved it was to:

- use a  Table chart
- add it to all pages
- everywhere but the from page (or wherever you want to interact with it):

  ```
    1. select table-> click on its settings (top right corner of the table, those 3 vertical dots) ->  "Send it to back"
    2. create white layer/shape large enough to cover the whole page and place it between the content you want visible and the table chart you want to hide ( Order-> Send backwards)
  ```

Does the trick. Hopefully there's also a less hacky solution out there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).